# C# - Class Method using Driven + Miles Used

Tags: c#

So I'm supposed to build a form with a class that calculates the miles driven and miles used to find out what the miles per gallon is.

In my form, my code:

```
 //Create a default value of 0.
        double dblDefault = 0;

        //Create a TryParse if the input is double, if not, show error message.
        if (!double.TryParse(txtDriven.Text, out dblDefault))
        {
            dblDefault = -1;
        }

        //Separation line...
        if (dblDefault >= -1)
        {
            double dblDriven = double.Parse(txtDriven.Text);
            double dblUsed = double.Parse(txtUsed.Text);

            CMilesPerGallon CTrans = new CMilesPerGallon();
            double dblMpgTotal = CMilesPerGallon.numofmiles(dblDriven);
            lblMpgTotal.Text = dblMpgTotal.ToString("C");
        }
        //If user inputs negative values, display message box for error.
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input, must be a positive 'double' value.");
        }
```

In my class, my code:

```
public class CMilesPerGallon
{
    //Create calculation method.
    public double calculate(double numofmiles, double numofgallons)
    {
        //Acquire the math.
        double mpg = numofmiles / numofgallons;

        //Return the MPG.
        return mpg;
    }
}
```

I know somewhere in there I did something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. The only error so far I got is, 'double dblMpgTotal = CMilesPerGallon.numofmiles(dblDriven)'. Because 'numofmiles'does not contain a definition.

Comment: did you mean to invoke the `calculate` method or do you have a  `numofmiles` method which you're not showing?

Comment: That is correct. So I swtiched it around a bit and did this,

'double dblMpgTotal = CMilesPerGallon.calculate(numofmiles, numofgallons);', but it says numofmiles and numofgallons doesn't exist in the context. It should exist because it's in my calculation method in my class? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: no, the parameters `numofmiles` and `numofgallons` are only accessible within the `calculate` method.

Comment: By the way, any method that takes an `out` parameter, like `TryParse` *guarantees* to assign a value to it. So there is no point in assigning a default value to `dblDefault`, and no need to parse `txtDriven.Text` a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method called `numofmiles` within your `CMilesPerGallon` class, However, I'd assume you wanted to pass `dblDriven` and `dblUsed` as the arguments to the `calculate` method.

e.g

```
double dblMpgTotal = CTrans.calculate(dblDriven, dblUsed);
```

note that the `calculate` method operates on the `CTrans` instance rather than being called directly via the class `CMilesPerGallon` as *it's not static*.

Comment: `CMilesPerGallon` does not have a method named `numofmiles()`. Your suggestion will still cause a compiler error. I suggest that you give a complete answer by showing the correct method to call.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i hope my updated answer does accomplish your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the code
- Calling the method with class name
- Calling a variable name as the method name and that variable also is not available in that scope.

I have kept your code to explain the problem and edited it to show how it should be called.

In the code part

```
CMilesPerGallon CTrans = new CMilesPerGallon();
double dblMpgTotal = CMilesPerGallon.numofmiles(dblDriven);
lblMpgTotal.Text = dblMpgTotal.ToString("C");
```

on the line

```
double dblMpgTotal = CMilesPerGallon.numofmiles(dblDriven);
```

You are calling the method `numofmiles` using the class name whereas you should use the object name you created as

```
double dblMpgTotal = CTrans.numofmiles(dblDriven);
```

Only static methods can be called with ClassName.MethodName. Using `cTrans` should fix your problem. And if you don't have a method `numofmiles` and you want to use `calculate` method then you just need to call as

```
double dblMpgTotal = CTrans.calculate(dblDriven, dblUsed);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no method named `numofmiles()`.

Comment: Yes, I assume the person who asked question has some misunderstanding on using some concepts. So I tried to keep the same code with explanation. Based on your comment, I have edited it so that he has final line as well, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, I am not providing the answer you were looking for, but trust me, I am providing the answer that you need. There are few basic concepts of programming that you need before you can go around and complete a full program. Seeing your question, I cannot give you a direct answer because truly there is none. But I will point you to the right direction, the rest depends on you.

Please try to collect the answers of the following questions, I am pretty sure, when you collect all the answers of the following questions, you will understand what was the problem -

- Difference between defining a Function/Method and executing Function/Method
- Passing Values as Parameters to functions
- What is Object Oriented Programming
- Difference between a class and object, similarly difference between class methods and object methods

There are more, but lets start with these.

Answer (score -1):

You have a misunderstanding of your variable scope. The variables `numofmiles` and `numofgallons` don't exist in your *calling* context, which uses `dblDriven` and `dblUsed`. So it should be:

```
double dblDriven = double.Parse(txtDriven.Text);
double dblUsed = double.Parse(txtUsed.Text);

CMilesPerGallon CTrans = new CMilesPerGallon();
double dblMpgTotal = CTrans.calculate(dblDriven, dblUsed);
```

Comment: There is no method named `numofmiles()`.

Comment: Also, `calculate()` is not a static method